# Shift +Menu as a hotkey in KDE

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

In KDE environment I have set <kbd>Menu</kbd> button as a hotkey for switching language layout. But it does not work when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed. So I need to set <kbd>Shift+Menu</kbd> as another hotkey for changing language layout. Is there a way to do that?